# Recursively delete folder in OneDrive for business

Tags: file-management, onedrive

[This Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-files-or-folders-in-onedrive-21fe345a-e488-4fa7-932b-f053c1bebe8a) states that

> - A personal OneDrive folder does not need to be empty before you delete it. However, you may want to check beforehand that there are no
>   files or sub-folders within it that you want to keep.
> - A work or school OneDrive for work or school folder must be empty before you can delete it.

Now, I need to delete a folder from OneDrive, which has over 100,000 files in over 2,000 folders 15 levels deep.  If I am to delete them one-by-one, I will be doing this for the next two years.  The only other recommendation I have seen is to disable file retention. This is not an option, as I am not an Office 365 admin; the organisation I work for has tens of thousands of employees and I don't even know who I should ask to disable this retention.

My local machine had been rebuild (i.e. windows reinstalled) - and onedrive doesn't recognise the fact that the files I have locally are the same as the ones in one-drive, causing sync issues.  I moved local files away - but that didn't help and the ones in onedrive are still reported as causing sync issues. I don't want these files to sync in the first place.

So, is there any other way to delete these files?  Maybe some sort of an automated script or anything else? Anything?

Comment: Shouldn't it just work to delete the first folder or were there still files that were needed?

Comment: I'm going thru this same issue.  What a waste of time.  I have so many folders that I uploaded as a backup.  These aren't files or folders that sync to my computer and now I need to delete them.  Currently navigating into each folder and then deleting the files/folders within each is taking up my entire morning.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive app on windows 10 allowed me the deletion of non-empty folders. And when it synced the files, the folders were deleted from the cloud as well.

Comment: Thanks.  This works fine for one drive personal - but not in onedrive for business, which is a different offering.

Comment: @AleksG - I actually did this on Onedrive for business. I accidentally uploaded some python repos to Onedrive(provided by my firm) and it had insane number of folders and subfolders/files. I got around that by deleting using the desktop app on windows. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Because work accounts do not allow deletion of folders that contain sub folders etc. you will have to use an alternative.

If you have both issues listed below, Perform up to and including step 14 in fixing OneDrive Sync then do the "Deleting deep folder structure workaround" and then return to step 15 in "Fix OneDrive Sync issue".

**Deleting deep folder structure workaround:**

Use the OneDrive's "Move To" option on the OneDrive website to move the folder to a SharePoint "Document Library" that you create specifically for this task and then delete the Document Library afterwards. If you do not have such permissions on a dedicated SharePoint site then most organizations that use OneDrive will also be using Teams, you can create a private team for yourself and then go to the files section and use the "Open in SharePoint" menu option to get to the backend SharePoint site where you will have permissions to make your own Document Library for this task.

To get to the OneDrive website:

- Click on the OneDrive icon in the notification area/system tray
- Click "View Online"
- IF IT TAKES LESS THAN 30 MINS TO MANUALLY NAVIGATE AND DELETE SUB FOLDERS AND FILES DO THAT INSTEAD OF THIS!
- DO NOT USE A DOCUMENT LIBRARY THAT OTHER PEOPLE USE - MAKE A NEW ONE - DON'T SCREW UP!

Using the "Follow" option on the SharePoint site that contains the newly created Document Library will make it easier to locate the destination when you use the "Move To" option... Its the star towards the upper right hand corner of the site.

**Fix OneDrive Sync issue:**

If you know the OneDrive cloud data is current in the cloud and you are ok with it replacing what you have on the local computer then you should be able to reset the sync...

1. Click on the OneDrive icon in the notification area/system tray
2. Click "View Online" - DO NOT CLOSE THIS WEBSITE.
3. Make sure this is this is the correct OneDrive contents you want and is current.
4. Click on the OneDrive icon in the notification area/system tray
5. Click Help & Settings.
6. Click Settings.
7. Click Account Tab.
8. Click Unlink this PC.
9. Confirm.
10. Make sure OneDrive is closed and no longer running.
11. Press Windows key and R together then run the following command.
12. %localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset
13. If OneDrive starts back up do not sign in yet.
14. You now have 2 options, try this with leaving the files you already have in place - if the sync doesn't work properly you will have to do it again using the other option. Or make a back up of the local one drive files and delete them. If you have enough hard drive space you can just rename the folder. The local location is normally something like "c:\users\yourusername\OneDrive - companyname" looking at the contents should verify it for you if you are in the right place or not.
15. Make sure OneDrive is running down in the system tray if not then click Windows button and type OneDrive, start the OneDrive app but do not sign in.
16. Back on the OneDrive web site you were told not to close, Click the Sync button that's above the "My files" section - it should now start OneDrive prompts back up, complete the prompts including sign in and pick the default settings the Organization has chosen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1107725)